# identify if excel cell has more than 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, excel

I have multiple excel files, i need to create a small tool(C#) where i need to create a log file to tell, which excel file and cell has more than 2 decimal places in it.
Also is it possible to highlight on excel cell which has more than 2 decimal places

Comment: what is the reason of -ve comment, i am not asking for code, i need some pointer with people's past exp.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, you should do it! How are you going to achieve this? What problem have you run into while developing this?

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible, i tried to iterate through all active(cell has value) cells

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Worksheet excelSheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
        var test = excelSheet.Cells[x, y].Value.ToString();
        int chk = GetDecimalCount(decimal.Parse(test));
```

Tool is now ready

[image]